# I've got problem showing " · " in website

Tags: html, unicode, doctype

I've got problem showing the character " · " in my website. I've never had any problem before showing other special characters. The character is a dot that is vertical middle aligned.

My doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

And my meta is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Do you have the special character directly in your document? If so, try using a HTML entity instead (`&middot;`).

Comment: Can you post a link? Are you having trouble with other Unicode characters on that same page? Did you check the headers to make sure it's actually interpreting as UTF-8? Why are you using such a complicated `charset` meta tag if you're working with HTML5? Why did you capitalize the "HTML" in the doctype? Why haven't you uploaded a user image yet? What significance does the number 87 hold for you? What are your hobbies? Do you have any dreams/goals/aspirations? How's your day been? What glyph does your site display *instead* of the ·?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HTML character code `&middot;`